# Is there a way to integrate Next.JS and a static plugin

Tags: javascript, next.js, plugins, static

I am working with Next.JS and I am trying to implement the Image Map Pro standalone plugin so that an interactive image map can be displayed on my site.

You cannot import this plugin dynamically so i've added the image map pro files into my plugin directory.

In order to display the image map, you need to do the following:

1. Paste this HTML code in your page, where you want the image map to appear.
   <div id="image-map-pro"></div>
2. Include the main Image Map Pro script file just before the closing body tag.
   <script src="image-map-pro.min.js"></script>
3. Paste this code below the included script.
   <script>ImageMapPro.init('#image-map-pro', {"id":"097b79bc-12e8-47d3-ac49-4b807138abd5","artboards":[{},{"id":"146a97df-c736-4731-afe9-53cee6eda646","title":"Artboard 0"}],"version":"6.0.8","general":{"name":"Untitled"}})</script>

See: https://imagemappro.com/docs/publishing-your-image

I tried doing this with Next Script but it comes back with this:

//Console

```
- error ReferenceError: ImageMapPro is not defined
    at RootLayout (./app/layout.jsx:103:27)
digest: "637352569"
  50 |       <Script src="/image-map-pro/image-map-pro.min.js" />
  51 |       <Script>
> 52 |         {ImageMapPro.init('#image-map-pro', {"id":"097b79bc-12e8-47d3-ac49-4b807138abd5","artboards":[{},{"id":"146a97df-c736-4731-afe9-53cee6eda646","title":"Artboard 0"}],"version":"6.0.8","general":{"name":"Untitled"}})}
     |         ^
  53 |       </Script>
  54 |     </html>
  55 |   );
```

//My Code

```
import NavBar from '../components/NavBar';
import { robotoSlab, roboto } from './fonts';
import './globals.css';
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import Script from 'next/script';
config.autoAddCss = false;

async function getData() {
const res = await fetch('http://homes.ychc.co.uk/api/developments/2')
if (!res.ok) {
throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
}
return res.json()
}
export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {

const data = await getData()

const mainStyle = {
backgroundImage: `url(${svgDataUrl})`,
backgroundSize: 'cover',
backgroundPosition: 'center',
backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
};

return (
\<html lang="en" className={`${robotoSlab.variable} ${roboto.variable}`}\>
\<body className="flex flex-col min-h-screen"\>
\<header\>
\<NavBar data={data} /\>
\</header\>
\<main style={mainStyle}\>
\<div id='image-map-pro'\>\</div\>
{children}
\</main\>
\<footer\>
\</footer\>
\</body\>
\<Script src="/image-map-pro/image-map-pro.min.js" /\>
\<Script\>
{ImageMapPro.init('#image-map-pro', {"id":"097b79bc-12e8-47d3-ac49-4b807138abd5","artboards":\[{},{"id":"146a97df-c736-4731-afe9-53cee6eda646","title":"Artboard 0"}\],"version":"6.0.8","general":{"name":"Untitled"}})}
\</Script\>
\</html\>
);
}
```

The script is definitely pointing to the correct place. I'm not sure if there is a quirk with Next concerning static plugins.